# Javascript asynchronous assignment and callback

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, variable-assignment

I'm sure there's an easy way to do this, but I'm having difficulty wrapping my mind around asynchronous calls and their flows. I'm trying to do a simple assignment statement in javascript, followed by setting a timer to perform operations on that object once it's been assigned. I have something along the lines of:

```
var info = getInfo();
$timeout(updateInfo(info), 5000);
```

However, I don't want the timeout to be executed until info is set initially. I've tried looking into using `.then` or some form of callback, but I haven't successfully determined how to do that. I'm unsure if having the parameter of `info` in the `updateInfo` call makes it so that I can't use callbacks in `getInfo` or what the correct flow is. I've read other articles and stack overflow responses, but couldn't find one dealing with asynchronous assignment and then using that as a paremter in a subsequent call.

`getInfo` and `updateInfo` are methods that return Highcharts graph config objects. Without copying over all the specific details:

```
getInfo: function() {
  return {
    options: {
      chart: {
        type: 'line'
      }
    }
    ...
  }
}

updateInfo: function(info) {
  // Here computations are performed on plot series data.
  info.series.push(...)
}
```

Comment: can you please share the implementations of `getInfo` and `updateInfo`? looks like you are using angular, is it so?

Comment: In case you haven't found it, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) is regarded as the canonical reference on stack overflow for this sort of thing, but yes - as @Shamun says, without seeing the details of the functions it's hard to say.

Comment: It should be `$timeout(function(info) { updateInfo(info); }, 5000);` at least. But unless `getInfo` works asynchronously, it should be ok.

Comment: yes angular is being used. and the getInfo and updateInfo methods perform manipulation on highcharts objects. added some brief code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `getInfo` and `updateInfo` looks pretty sync to me.
So there shouldn't be any synchronization problem.

The only thing I noticed is the wrong use of `$timeout` in your example.
`$timeout(updateInfo(info), 5000);` this way `updateInfo` will be called before the timeout starts and the returned value will be passed as a parameter.

In order to call `updateInfo` after 5 seconds you have to use anonymous function or `bind` function.

`$timeout(function() { updateInfo(info); }, 5000);`

`$timeout(updateInfo.bind(null, info), 5000);`

For more info about [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind).

Answer (score 1):

You should remember that although JavaScript does some asynchronous actions, yet the assignment to a variable is synchronous, which means that it occurs at the moment you requested for it, and won't go on to the next line until it's done.

If `getInfo` itself has the variable info in scope and updates it during the asynchronous call, then you shouldn't assign a value to it in the invocation of the function.

If I confused you, let me guess what you do there (and please provide the getInfo function for clarifying your question).

I'm pretty sure what `getInfo` does is an ajax call. So if you already use jQuery, you can simply use their ajax function:

```
function getInfo(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "/api/items"
    }).done(updateInfo);
}

function updateInfo(data){
      console.log ('Do something with', data);
}

getInfo();
```

See full documentation:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/